# PhpMailer - use $to adress from database

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to submit forms on a website. It's loaded as a function, then each page calls it as needed.

What I want to do is add the "$to" address from the database, instead of hard coding it. I'm the site manager/designer and have been able to maintain it but can't find any docs/wiki to outline how this might work.

My script looks like this:

```
    $to = 'info@website.com';
    $from = 'info@website.com';
    $subject = 'RSVP From Website';
    $cc = '';
    $bcc = '';

    $message = $given['eventName'];
    $message .= '<p><strong>Name:</strong><br />'.to_html($given['name']).'</p>'."\n";
    $message .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong><br />'.to_html($given['email']).'</p>'."\n";
    $message .= '<p><strong>Company:</strong><br />'.to_html($given['company']).'</p>'."\n";
    $message .= '<p><strong>Phone:</strong><br />'.to_html($given['phone']).'</p>'."\n";
    $message .= '<p><strong># Attending:</strong> <br/>'.to_html($given['attending']).'</p>'."\n";
    ... and so on
```

The regular syntax for echoing the recipient on the front end would look like this:

```
    '.to_html($event[$recipient]).'
```

So the "$to" woudl be like this:

```
    $to = ''.to_html($recipient).'';
```

I know that the script doesn't pass the recipient onto the phpmailer script. I just don't know how to write that one line.

Comment: Have you tried `$to = $recipient`?

Comment: hmmm no i have not. Will do right away though!

Comment: nope that doesn't work.

Comment: What does `to_html` do? What is the value of `$given['email']`?

Comment: try     
     $to = to_html($recipient);
and what string you see on the page? is it valid email

Comment: I want $to = echo $event['recipient']; to work, but it doesn't seem to either

Comment: to_html just called something from the database. $given is the input someone puts into the form

Comment: AND it's hard to see the output, as it just fired an email off into the black hole of the internet.